# How to check spaces in a string C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, error-handling

I am trying to have my program take a name as input from the user and then print out the initials of that name. i.e. tommy brown --> tb

What I have so far is this:

```
int main (void)
{

char scroll[100] = {"kang cheng junga"};
printf ("%c\n", *(scroll+2));

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    if (*(scroll+i)=" ")
    {
        printf (*(scroll+i+1));
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> error: incompatible pointer to integer
>         conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]'
>
> [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
>       if (*(scroll+i)=" ")
>
> error: using the result of an assignment as a
>         condition without parentheses
>
> [-Werror,-Wparentheses]
>       if (*(scroll+i)=" ")

Can anyone tell me how I've screwed this up? I am having a hard time understanding how * and & function in a C. I am a beginner so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Basic thing: `=` should be `==`

Comment: **if (*(scroll+i)=" ") ==>  if (*(scroll+i)==' ')** compare characters not character and string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `strtok`, this is one time you can also make use of `strpbrk` to easily find each `space`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char scroll[100] = "kang cheng junga";
    char *p = scroll;

    printf ("\n full name: %s\n", scroll);
    printf (" initials : %c", *p);

    while ((p = strpbrk (p, " ")))
            printf ("%c", *++p);

    printf ("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/initials

 full name: kang cheng junga
 initials : kcj
```

You can also eliminate the dependence on `string.h` with an alternative version that uses pointers alone:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char scroll[100] = "kang cheng junga";
    char *p = scroll;

    printf ("\n full name: %s\n", scroll);
    printf (" initials : %c", *p);

    while (*p++)
        if (*p == ' ' && *++p)
            printf ("%c", *p);

    printf ("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am curious how to print the rest of the string after detecting the first white space, like "cheng junga" in this case

Comment: The simple way is `p = strchr (scroll, ' '); puts (p + 1);`

Comment: This is working perfectly. Now as soon as I am trying to read 'scroll' via input stream     
" for (i=0;i<100;i++){
    scanf("%s", scroll[i]);
    } "
program is not proceeding further after scanning user input. Any tips?

Comment: When you start reading from an input stream, you should read a line-at-a-time into a buffer with `fgets()` and then parse what you need from the buffer using `sscanf()`. This ensures you consume a line of input each read and a variation in format does not break your input. For example `char buf[256]; while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { char first[64], middle[64], last[64]; if (sscanf (buf, "%s %s %s", first, middle, last) == 3) printf ("\nfirst: %s\nmiddle: %s\nlast: %s\n", first, middle, last); }` You can copy `buf` or any of the substrings to save as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Error you are getting is because of the assignment operator (=) .

```
if (*(scroll+i)=" ")// assigning a value(blank)
{
    printf (*(scroll+i+1));
}

if (*(scroll+i) == ' ')//Comparing it with a value (blank)
{
    printf (*(scroll+i+1));
}
```

Comment: @noggy Also Why have you taken the limits to 100?. Unnecessarily executing the **for loop 100 times**

Comment: *(scroll+i) == " " ; -> *(scroll+i) == ' ' ;

Comment: This method throws warning: `comparison between pointer and integer` and  I don't allow my code to have any warnings, it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `=` is assignment operator, and `==` is equality operator. You need to use the later one.

That said, there is a nice library function, named [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) which can make your life easier. Just pass the string and a delimiter, (here, the space ) and it will return the token to you, for which you can print the first character to get the initials.

Answer (score 0):

along with strtok or strchr here is a simple way to implement , some boundary conditions are missing like name ending with single letter etc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

        int i = 0;
        char scroll[100] = {"kang cheng junga"};
        char *p = scroll; // point to base
        printf("%c", *p ); // first letter is almost always certain
        while( *p != '\0' ) { // till end of String

                if ( *(p-1)     == ' ' && *(p+1) != '\0') { // If previous is space and next letter exists
                        printf("%c", *p );      // take it save it or print it
                }
                p ++ ; //proceed
        }

        return 0;
}
```